# Accessing Google related resources using QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, google-api-cpp-client

So I've done some digging, but came up with nothing thus far because I feel that this would be a close to impossible task. But I am more than willing to look on my own, I wanted to know if it was possible to access Google related resources using QT Creator. So For example if I wanted to use say Google analytics, what would I need to research? Would I need to have some sort of app-engine side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can access most of the Google products by using the corresponding API (AppEngine is not required for that). [This link lists all available Google APIs](http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer). You can then access it using [the Google API Client for C++](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/cpp/), but the C++ binding seems to be in alpha.

Edit:
It seems that Google stopped the development and support of the C++ binding for their APIs. The library source code can still be found [on Github](https://github.com/google/google-api-cpp-client).

Comment: "_The Google APIs C++ Client Library is no longer available. Thank you for your interest._" :(

Comment: @fduff you can still [get it from Github](https://github.com/google/google-api-cpp-client) but yes, it won't be supported anymore and I guess it will slowly die.